# Flink source consume redundant serde operations

Tags: protocol-buffers, apache-flink

I have a Flink consumer which ingests protobuf objects from a Kafka topic, it is then rebalanced into a filter operator to reduce the amount of processing. The current topology looks like this

```
|--------------|                    |--------------|
|              |                    |              |
| Kafka Source | --- rebalance -->  |    Filter    | --- hash to other logic operators... -->
|              |                    |              |
|--------------|                    |--------------|
```

The current topology seems to suggest that Flink will consume the protobuf objects, deserialize it, then re-serialize it to rebalance towards the filter operator which will *again* be deserialized and processed. Is this understanding correct? If so, how can I avoid this and optimize serde operations?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records transferred between operators will be serialized/deserialized by default in Flink, except that the operators are chained together and object reuse is enabled.

1. Flink by default chains operators if this is possible, e.g. a filter function followed by a map function, with the same parallism, will be chained together. In contrast, functions after a keyby won't be chained together with those before it. Chaining reduces thread-to-thread handover and buffer overhead, but serialization and deserialization still occur within one chain.
2. If you [enable object reuse](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/execution/execution_configuration/), records transferred between operators won't be serialized/deserialized and you save this overhead. They'll be passed as Java object instances just as if you pass a parameter to a function. But as the documentation says:

> Keep in mind that this can lead to bugs when the user-code function of an operation is not aware of this behavior.

Comment: What kind of bugs can occur here? Can you provide an example case?

Comment: Without object reuse, records in different operators are different Java object instances, althrough they may have the same value. 
With object reuse, records in different operators within one chain group are the same instance. If you cache the record in previous operator and use it later, you might find it modified unexpectedly, by subsequent operators. If you forward the record to another thread in one operator for asynchronous processing, there might be a race condition because the same instance might also be used by another operator later.